# Can every DFA be simulated by a PDA?

Tags: proof, finite-automata, state-machine, non-deterministic, pushdown-automaton

Given a Deterministic Finite Automata (DFA) M_1, does there always exist a Pushdown Automata (PDA) M_2 that accepts the same language as M_1?  I.e. **can any DFA be simulated by a PDA?**  Intuitively, it makes sense to me that a PDA is more powerful since it has an arbitrary amount of memory and can therefore accept more languages than a DFA, but how could this be formally proven?

Comment: Rather, an NFA **is** a PDA that just doesn't use its stack. NFAs and DFAs are computationally equivalent. A PDA **is** a nondeterministic Turing Machine that only looks at the most recently written item on its tape. The way to formalize the proof is to map an NFA's definition into a PDA's definition. I.e., given an NFA `<q0, S={q1,q2,...}, d:<qi,c> -> qk, sigma, F>`, create PDA `<S, sigma, empty set, d:<qi, c, null> -> qk, q0, null, F>`. This PDA accepts the same language as the NFA. Hand-wavely, this PDA can only follow transitions to accepting states the way the original NFA would.

Answer (score 0):

A finite automaton is nothing but a Turing machine that does not use its memory.  A PDA is nothing but a Turing machine that restricts its access to its memory to LIFO.

So, a finite automaton *is* a PDA.